# identify json object consisting of different number of items

Tags: javascript, php, json

Here is my `json` object

```
[  
{  
    "grup":"",
    "barkod":"1234",
    "amount":"1",
    "selling price":"215",
    "cost":"68.69"
},
{  
    "grup":"4444",
    "barkod":"",
    "ammount":"1",
    "selling price":"49.9",
    "cost":"75"
},
{  
    "grup":"3333",
    "barkod":"091986 ",
    "amount":"1",
    "selling price":"69.9",
    "cost":"16.56"
},
{  
    "cost":"300",
    "pay type":"cash",
    "taksit":"1"
},
{  
    "cost":"200",
    "pay type":"BANK",
    "taksit":"7"
},
{  
    "idNo":""
}
]
```

this object is sent via ajax  php  server. Then, turns it into a php array:

```
 $datax = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

I want  for first 3  elements (number can change)   run insert statment for `table1`,
for 4. and 5. elements  run insert statment for `table2`  and so on

Comment: Would you show me what you have written in PHP side?

Comment: actually first 3 elements  represents  tree products's selling information . and 4. and 5. element represents  pay information

Comment: You just asked a vague question I want to see your efforts, how much you have done?

Comment: it is my unfluent english , 
it is okey . for example first 3 elements consist of 5 item then use product table,    4. and 5. element consist of 3 item then use paytable ; I need if condition and identification of element number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print first object, you should use this:

```
print_r(datax[0]);
```

I'm writing an example statement for MySQL here, so you can edit it for your own code.

```
$grup = $datax[0]->grup;
$firma_barkod = $datax[0]->firma_barkod;
$adet = $datax[0]->adet;
$birim_satis_fiyati = $datax[0]->birim_satis_fiyati;
$birim_maliyet = $datax[0]->birim_maliyet;

$query = "INSERT INTO table_name (grup, firma_barkod, adet, birim_satis_fiyati, birim_maliyet)
VALUES ('$grup', '$firma_barkod', '$adet', '$birim_satis_fiyati', '$birim_maliyet');
```

I'm just make you understand the logic; if you want to reach first element, you should use `$datax[0]`, if you want to reach fourth element you should use `$datax[3]`

Comment: it is okey .   for example  first  3 elements consist of 5 item then  use product table  and 4. and 5. element consist of 3 item then use paytable ; I  need if condition

Comment: So, you should count items of array am I right? Than you'll use if condition?

Comment: OK than use `count`. For example; `if (count($datax[0] == 4) { //...do something }`

Comment: it does not give number of elements  when i write count($datax[0])

Comment: Because you're decoding json wrong, you should use this: `json_decode($yourjsonvariable, TRUE);` `TRUE` is important.